# Which syntactic dependency parsers perform best on search query phrases?

Tags: syntax, computational-linguistics, parsing, dependency-grammar

Lots of NLP libraries contain syntactic dependencies parsers (e.g. spaCy, NLTK, Stanford NLP, Spark NLP...). As I understand it (please correct me if I'm wrong), these are mostly designed to parse complete natural sentences. But what if your use case is parsing phrases like search queries, which tend to be (a) NPs or other sub-sentence constituents and (b) written without articles? A parser that performs well on "The man was standing on the bridge" might not necessarily handle "man standing on bridge" equally well.

Which existing parsers perform best on such phrases?

Most interested in English-specific answers but more general ones would be great too.